# Creating a mapping between all the nodes with text and their xpaths

Tags: python, xpath

I have an Html page. I want to find out xpath of all the text nodes present there and store them in an excel file.

Code

```
start_path='.//tr|.//div[not(ancestor::div)][not(descendant::tr)]'
row_data_points=hxs.select(start_path)
for r in row_data_points:
    row=r.select('.//text()').extract()
    path_prefix='('+start_path+')['+str(row_data_points.index(r)+1)+']'
    row=[x.replace('\n','').replace('\t','') for x in row]
    row=[x for x in row if x.strip()!='']
    d={}
    for r1 in row:
        path=path_prefix+"//*[text()="+"'"+r1+"'"+"]"
        #path
        stg="var element=document.evaluate("+'"'+path+'"'+",document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;return element.getBoundingClientRect()"
        print "trying",stg
        print "1111",stg
        d[row.index(unidecode(r1))]={'value':unidecode(r1),'loc':driver.execute_script(str(stg))}
```

The problem is coming when there are unwanted characters coming when i get all the text nodes using `(.//text)` and then i create a xpath using the text node. it can not find the element.
Is there any other way or any library already present to do so.

Comment: Can you post the URL or at least a representative part of the html code and an example of your desired output?

Comment: Hey thanks, but i found a way out using javascript. thanks for the help